# Наложение двух текстур WebGl

Tags: opengl, webgl

Написано на WebGl, используя шейдеры.

Есть карта, состоящая из двух объектов, камня и травы.
[image: карта]

Сверху же мне нужно наложить белую сетку, которая разделяла бы блоки на карте, сетка в формате png. Как это возможно осуществить?

Я пробовал рисовать сначала карту, а после поверх сетку, но получалось не так, как задумывалось. Текстура сетки полностью перекрывает карту.
[image: карта с сеткой]

Comment: Решено. По умолчанию функция смешивания выключена в webgl, поэтому нужно включить её самостоятельно, а после указать, каким образом производить смешивание цветов, в моём случае это выглядело вот так:
    gl.enable( gl.BLEND );
    gl.blendFunc( gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: Вам следует разместить ваш ответ в качестве ответа, и отметить его галкой, как правильный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию функция смешивания выключена в webgl, поэтому нужно включить её самостоятельно, а после указать, каким образом производить смешивание цветов, в моём случае это выглядело вот так:

```
gl.enable( gl.BLEND ); 
gl.blendFunc( gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```